# Deploying web app on Stratos Live

Tags: wso2, wso2-stratos

I Need to deploy a web application on Stratos server. I went through this blog post http://dakshithar.blogspot.com/2011/08/how-to-deploy-web-application-in.html and this slideshow http://engwar.com/p/java-paas-gs/#wa01.  They have information on deploying a web app to Stratos using Eclipse and Carbon Studio.

I have already created my web application on Netbeans IDE, so is there anyway to configure Carbon Studio with Netbeans?

Is it necessary to use Carbon Studio with Eclipse application deployment, or can I run web applications that I have developed in Netbeans on Stratos Live server?  Or is migrating from Netbeans to Eclipse the only option?

Comment: Found the answer, it is not necessary to use Carbon Studio with Eclipse, We can use neatbeans to develop the app and, can deploy the .war fileon stratoes live server.We can deploy apps developed by another IDE without any problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Carbon studio** is a Eclipse-based SOA development environment for the Carbon platform.Here are the Answers for your questions.

Q :- Is there anyway to configure Carbon Studio with Netbeans?

A :- NO,since carbon studio is eclipse based tooling environment it can not be configured with Netbeans.

Q :- Is it necessary to use Carbon studio with Eclipse application deployment can I run web applications that I have developed in Netbeans on Stratos Live server?

A :- When it comes to web application development,it is not necessary to use Carbon studio for Stratos Live or WSO2 Application server deployment.But if you going to develop any other SOA components with WSO2 products life will be easier with Carbon Studio.

As an alternative you can import your .war file (that you already have) in to carbon studio by using New Web Application wizard.